# ffmpeg says "this file requires zlib suport compiled in"

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, zlib

I've created a new conda environment and installed zlib and opencv. However, sometimes this error raises (but doesn't interrupt script execution):

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001d18e775800] this file requires zlib support compiled in
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001d18e775800] error reading header
```

Is there a chance to fix this issue under windows? When using WSL this error doesn't show up, but then the program randomly terminates printing "Killed" (without any error). I already tried to uninstall opencv using conda and install opencv-python using pip, but I got the same error.

Comment: that's a message coming from ffmpeg. you seem to have an OpenCV that comes with ffmpeg which _doesn't_ come with zlib. what are you even trying to read there, can you provide that file for examination? -- "error doesn't show up" but program *crashes*? that counts as it still being an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! The hint with ffmpeg bumped me in the right direction. So what I did: First installed zlib, then installed ffmpeg with the conda-forge channel and then installed opencv. Now everything is working fine, thanks!

Comment: please feel encouraged to post that as an answer. perhaps go into details a bit. I think this would be a valuable Q&A pair. this is the first question to mention that error on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Christoph Rackwitz suggested, the error wasn't related to OpenCV but to FFmpeg. So what I did to resolve the issue:

```
conda create --name myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install zlib
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
conda install opencv
```

This process installs an FFmpeg version compiled with zlib support and the error is gone.